# In WPF, how can I restrict selection in a DataGrid to only be cells in the same row or column?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, selection, multi-select

We have a DataGrid that allows the user to multi-select cells. However, we have a unique business requirement.  Specifically...

1. First cell: You can select anywhere
2. Second cell: Has to be either in the same row or the same column as the first cell.
3. Additional cells: Has to be in the same row or column as defined by the second cell.

I don't see any PreviewSelectionChanges methods to use, nor do I see any way to block Shift-Selections that would cross the boundaries of the allowable selection.

My current thought is to maintain an `int? Row;` and `int? Col;` properties which I use to prune the selected cells after I get the selection changed event, but that seems to me to not really be that clear since it's happening after the fact.  I want something that says 'Cell(c,r) is about to become selected.  Will you allow it?' and I can go from there.

So... Thoughts?

Comment: I recommend either creating your own grid from scratch or looking to third parties like DevExpress or Telerik. I found the built-in data grid to be both buggy and hard to extend.

Comment: The built-in grid is a horrible excuse for a grid.  I can't believe how many issues it has!!  I've since switched to Xceed which is much more complicated than it needs to be and is missing certain simple things, but it's damn stable.  Still, as I said, it's a beast!  (Just snoop it!  Your jaw will hit the floor!)  I really may just roll my own that I can use for simple layout tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I can think of to get the information a bit earlier would be to tap into the MouseDown event.  It wouldn't be pretty because the `MouseDown` location does not necessarily indicate where the `MouseUp` will be but it is generally true.  Therefore, if you determine that the `MouseDown` is in a "forbidden" cell you could alert the user or perform whatever other tasks you wanted to do.

You could also put a check in the `MouseClick` event (I believe this is the one) to first check to see if the cell being selected is a "forbidden" cell.  If it is, you could cancel the event which should stop the cell from being selected.  Depending on how the `DataGrid` works (I haven't been able to test it yet), you might need to do this for a couple Mouse events.

Comment: The problem with that approach is it's restricted to mouse input, not keyboard.  Still, since no one else has answered and this is getting stale, I'm gonna go ahead and vote you up anyway.  Helps us both.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success by responding to the SelectedCellsChanged event and adjusting the selection.  Here I define the 'same column' to be the leftmost column which means dragging left switches which column is selected but it would be simple enough to remember which column was first selected and restrict to that one.

For example:

```
void DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e) {
   DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;

   var first_cell = dg.SelectedCells.FirstOrDefault();
   if (first_cell != null) {
      var ok_col = first_cell.Column;
      var to_remove = dg.SelectedCells.Where(c => c.Column != ok_col).ToList();
      foreach (var c in to_remove) dg.SelectedCells.Remove(c);
   }
}
```